# Index of inserted ListView item

Tags: c#, listview

How can i get the index when adding my item to the ListView?

Im adding the item as follows

```
flatListView1.Items.Add(name).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need this, as the item added at the end of listitem and will be last. So total items -1 will be index because index starting from zero.

```
flatListView1.Items.Add(name).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
int index = flatListView1.Items.Count -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var lviewItem=flatListView1.Items.Add(name)
var index=flatListView1.Items.IndexOf(lviewItem)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.indexof.aspx